# Non Parameterless Constructor Binding Nancy (Model.Bind)

Tags: c#, nancy

I have recently moved our WebApi to Nancy. So far, so good, but I am having an issue which I am not sure how to resolve.

We maintain a lot of legacy apps which traditionally deal with database access directly. To facilitate the move to our new REST based system we created an indirection which allows the legacy app to send a "command" and receive a dataset, it's not ideal but it allows us to move legacy systems in a reliable fashion.

Using WebApi the command object from the request body was deserialized into a model (via Json.Net) without issue using `[FromBody]`. However when using Nancy an exception is thrown, it expects a parameterless constructor.

I don't like the idea of modifying the model to suit Nancy. Is there a way to have Nancy deserialize and bind the Json in the request like WebApi? I notice Nancy handles Json serialization internally, is it simply a case of brining Json.Net into the mix?

**Constructor In Question:**

```
  public DbCommandContainer(DatabaseType databaseType, 
                            CommandType commandType, 
                            string text, 
                            int timeout, 
                            IEnumerable<DbParameterContainer> parameters)
```

**EDIT:**

I have pulled in Json.Net and used it to manually deserialize the body stream. This works fine which means I simply need to set Json.Net to be the default Body deserializer I think.

Comment: We have a package for Json.Net, if you install Nancy.Serialization.JsonNet it will wire itself up automatically.

Comment: I think we discussed this in Jabbr. The default binding doesn't handle models with constructors, you could modify the Json.Net package to handle this and submit a PR and maybe its something we consider for the default nancy binder.

Comment: Correct Jon, this preceeded that conversation, do you want to add an answer and we can mark as resolved?